# Nativescript: Use NativeScript UI with plain javascript

Tags: nativescript

I'm building a app with just javascript, no typescript, no angular, no vuejs.

Is it possible to use NativeScript UI with pure javascript ?

I'm trying to use radlistview, and the only code I find is on TypeScript.

If not, then what I'm trying to do is just output a list and tapAction on each item to navigato to single item with the data passed of that item.

Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very possible.  In many of the examples you'll have to mentally translate from typescript to javascript.  I use javascript projects myself and had to make those translations myself when I was first starting.  It can be a little confusing.

Comment: Just know that the tap action receives as its binding context the array entry in the list view.  It's very helpful to pause in the debugger on entry to the tap action and inspect the relationships of the various objects.  So, args.object = control that was tapped, args.object.bindingContext = array entry, and args.object.page = page object.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of TypeScript / Angular / Vue, end of the code is complied to plain JavaScript only. These are just modern frameworks / libraries those help to speed up development & make things easier.

The TypeScript code can be compiled into JavaScript using TypeScript CLI, there are even several sites do this within your browser.

**RadListView: ViewModel**

```
var frame = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame");
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

function HomeViewModel() {

  var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({

    countries: [
      { name: "Australia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/au.png" },
      { name: "Belgium", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/be.png" },
      { name: "Bulgaria", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/bg.png" },
      { name: "Canada", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ca.png" },
      { name: "Switzerland", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ch.png" },
      { name: "China", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/cn.png" },
      { name: "Czech Republic", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/cz.png" },
      { name: "Germany", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/de.png" },
      { name: "Spain", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/es.png" },
      { name: "Ethiopia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/et.png" },
      { name: "Croatia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/hr.png" },
      { name: "Hungary", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/hu.png" },
      { name: "Italy", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/it.png" },
      { name: "Jamaica", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/jm.png" },
      { name: "Romania", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ro.png" },
      { name: "Russia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ru.png" },
      { name: "United States", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/us.png" },
    ],

    onItemTap: function (args) {
      var bindingContext = args.view.bindingContext;
      console.log(bindingContext.name);
    },

  });

  return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=SiPZYa)

Comment: Thanks that works. I had args.object.bindingContext instead. Awesome.